# Need help to understand and implement basic web app security

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am learning basic web app security from "head first jsp and servlets". There is no code for the security app except `web.xml` and `tomcat-users.xml` settings. I followed the book and tried to make my own code, but I am not able to control access to my web app.

Anyone can access it despite setting the roles in tomcat-users.xml and editing `web.xml`. Please help me to understand this and complete my example. I am using Eclipse kepler and Tomcat 6.0.

**Eclipse project:**

[image]

**Expectation:** Run `start.html` and click the `submit button` to access `SecureServlet`. Container should ask you for a login to access that servlet. If the login matches the one in `web.xml` settings, then you are shown the `secret.jsp` page.

**Output:** There is no security. You can see `secret.jsp` without entering any login.

**Tomcat-users.xml:**

```
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="Admin"/>
<role rolename="Member"/>
<role rolename="Guest"/>

<user username="jim" password="admin" roles="Admin, Member, Guest" />
<user username="tim" password="premium" roles="Member, Guest" />
<user username="fred" password="regular" roles="Guest" />

</tomcat-users>
```

**web.xml:** 
Put the code in both tomcat's web.xml and my web app's web.xml to be safe.

```
  <web-app> 
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>WebSecurity</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/secretServlet</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Admin</role-name>
      <role-name>Member</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Member</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Guest</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>

  <!--If web app web. xml, then add the mapping below-->
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SecretServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SecretServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.SecretServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SecretServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SecretServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Html start page:**

```
Enter here:<br>
<form method=post action="/WebSecurity/SecretServlet" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="try to access!">
</form>
```

**Servlet:**

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SecretServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SecretServlet() {
        super();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/secret.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/secret.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**secret.jsp:**

```
<h3>Congratulations ! You entered the secure area.</h3>
```

Comment: Please share your web.xml configuration

Comment: @Javakid - I edited the question. web.xml is visible now.

Comment: As a note, hand-writing servlets is a Bad Idea, and even JSP is awfully clumsy compared to some more modern technologies like Thymeleaf. By all means learn about the plumbing of the system, but for real work I highly suggest a framework such as Spring MVC (and Spring Boot can even do most of the security setup for you).

Comment: @chrylis - thanks. one step at a time. i need to master jsp, servlets before i can do spring and all the other good stuff. See - http://www.coderanch.com/t/633527/Spring/JSP-Servlets-Spring-Developers-Spring#2901760

Comment: Note that you really don't need to understand servlets to use something like Spring MVC; all of the servlet plumbing is handled for you. You can just write a Java method that uses POJOs, and Spring will adapt everything for you.

Comment: @chrylis - That is my biggest dilemma. Bear, a respected author says that basic knowledge of jsp servlets is a must. I don't know for sure. Maybe I will know once I learn spring in depth.

Comment: Answer - `<url-pattern>/secretServlet</url-pattern>` change it to SecretSerlvet. Duh !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `<url-pattern>` as below and try

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Btw, do I have to put the login code in tomcat web.xml or my web app's web.xml ?

Comment: Did the above work? You mean <login-config>? Everything else looks okay. Just try by changing the <url-pattern>

Comment: Thanks. That works. I just realized that I made one mistake in web app's web.xml file - S should be capital in SecretServlet. Duh !